# Migrating Site To Digital Ocean and having trouble with redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, http, redirect, https

I am migrating my site to digital ocean and I am having an issue with Https. I have moved the directory and the apache2 config file and mysql database. I believe I set everything up correctly but now I want to test it. I have edited my /etc/hosts file with my new ip and sitename.com. However when I try to go to my browser and look to see if the site works it keeps trying to redirect me to the https version of my site.
I have tried going to chrome://net-internals/#hsts and deleting the site but it still redirects to https. How can I test my site without being redirected to the still hosted version of my site?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you wordpress setup is set to https. You have to change these settings. You can do this in database too. Table wp_config

Comment: I checked my database and I cant see the wp_config table. It jumps directly to wp_links from comments 
Expand/CollapseStructurewp_commentmeta
Expand/CollapseStructurewp_comments
Expand/CollapseStructurewp_links

Comment: Ok I was able to edit the wp_options field in the database and changed the https to http. In doing so I was able to get access to the wp-admin backend for my wordpress site. However whenever I click on view any page it still redirects me to https

Answer (score 0):

Aside of the wp_options field, WordPress stores lot's of links 'hard-coded' which all will contain the https. You would need to do a full search and replace on the database, but be aware of serialized stuff. To to safely perform a search and replace you could use a program found on: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Works like a charm.

Another way is by using wpcli if you have commandline access and wpcli is available. From the command line go to your root directory (containing the index.php) and type:

```
wp search-replace https://www.your-domain.example http://www.your-domain.example
```

Or type:

```
wp search-replace https://your-domain.example http://your-domain.example
```

Based on your setup up course.

Always make a full backup of your database before performing these actions, so you can restore if any problems occur.